# Clearcase failed to get license w/ Rational Common Licensing

Tags: clearcase, flexlm

Some background info, I am evaluating on Clearcase, and I have setup my environment like this:

1. Clearcase server (VOB and View servers) installed on my Windows XP
2. Clearcase client installed in the virtual machine on the same XP, with bridged network
3. I used Common Licensing

The problem I am facing is, I can get license on my server XP, but not on my client virtual XP, the following error is returned:

```
File path: C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalRLKS\common............27000@<my host name>;
FLEXnet Licensing error:-96,491
```

Some sources suggested about specifying the vendor daemon port, but I have no idea how to check what is the current daemon port and how to change it, anyone has idea?

More information about FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147

```
cleartool: Error: License checkout error from Rational Common Licensing:
The FEATURE name RLPwCC with version 1.0 cannot be found
License server system does not support this feature.
Feature:       RLPwCC
License path:  C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalRLKS\common\rational_perm.dat;C:\Program Files
\IBM\RationalRLKS\common\rational_temp.dat;27000@<my host name>;
FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147
For further information, refer to the FLEXnet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
cleartool: Error: You do not have a license to run ClearCase.
```

Comment: Have you checked if the port is opened? try netstat -an | findstr "LISTEN"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hit another problem about "FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147". I have added license key in my server, and I can telnet my license server in port 27000. Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For evaluation purpose, I would recommend asking IBM for a simple file for **[Atria licensing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21128958)**, instead of having to start a [Flexlm server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21388562).

But if you have a FlexNet license key, you can see the technote "[Resolving FLEXnet Licensing Error: -96, 491](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21324011)" (for Telelogic, but you can adapt it for ClearCase).

> To assign a specific port to the Telelogic DAEMON, (example: 19354) add the string " `PORT=19354` " at the end of the `VENDOR` line in the license file.
>   For example:

```
VENDOR telelogic "C:\Program Files\Telelogic\Tools\Licensing_11\Server\telelogic.exe" PORT=19354
```

> Ensure that the port 19354 (or whichever port number you have chosen to specify) is open for bi-directional communication by the Firewall.
>   You can use any bi-directionally open port as a fixed port for the Telelogic vendor daemon, so long as the port is not being used by any other application.

---

The [OP Arthas Tsang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204799/arthas-tsang) reports then having the error:

```
FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147
```

The actual cause is generally mentioned *after* that part, as for example illustrated in the technote "[FLEXlm error: 18,147 is reported if RLPwCC licenses are in use and ClearCase commands are run from a non-root cron job](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398710)" (if your ClearCase isn't started with admin privileges)

---

Regarding "The FEATURE name RLPwCC with version 1.0 cannot be found", many messages state an issue with the installation of the license server (like [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14689029))

> Problem Solved after installing the Latest Version of the License Server.

Check this [technote to get just the License server](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21265239).

---

Regarding the "System clock setback detected", [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21396487) mentions several causes:

- If there is a Server / Client setup then the most likely cause of the error is a discrepancy in the time/date between the server and the other machines in the network.
  Resolution.
- Cause 2: The system on which the licenses are set up has been Back Dated.
- Cause 3: If there are files present on the OS that are dated past the current date.

(See also [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421615))

And the [OP Arthas Tsang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204799/arthas-tsang) does report it was indeed a **time-stamp issue**:

> I finally found two files, neither of them related to FlexLM, with timestamps marked in 2014.
>   After removing those files, the license works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hit another problem about "FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147". I have added license key in my server, and I can telnet my license server in port 27000. Any idea about this problem?

Comment: @ArthasTsang: I have edited my answer, but do you have any other error message after the "`FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147`" initial one?

Comment: I have posted the detailed error in my question. Besides, I found that in the lmgrd log on my license server, it has error "16:20:05 (ibmratl) System clock setback detected", which exist even after I reinstall the license server, but I have never changed the system clock of my computer......

Comment: @ArthasTsang: answer updated to reflect your new error messages

Comment: Thanks Von, I finally found two files, neither of them related to FlexLM, with timestamps marked in 2014. After removing those files, the license works fine

Comment: @ArthasTsang I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.